# Generating Different SHA1 for different modules with different package name in Same Project

Tags: android, sha1

I don't know if it is possible or not, but can it be possible to have different SHA1 in same project for different package named modules.These modules are different apps i.e., one for user and one for admin. While creating project i found that using modules will be great but i think now i got confused whether i should have different project or can be possible with this. Since i have to add the firebase cloud messaging to both modules. It is showing sha1 already used since both modules are having same SHA1.
I have checked every where but didn't found about it anywhere .

Comment: The hash is based on the signing certificate you used for signing the apps. If they are the same, then the SHA-1 hash will be the same.

Comment: But i didn't created any signing certificate it's in development @Michael

Comment: Well, you haven't provided any real details on how you got these SHA-1 hashes. But even if your APKs aren't signed with a production keystore yet, they're probably signed with some debug keystore.

Comment: you are right @Michael, i even have added the different keystore files. And is using gradle to generate the key from signing report options.

Comment: but it still didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can have different product flavors and different signing config. Also take a note that each certificate you will have different sha1.(https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)

```
 signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file("debug.keystore.jks")
        storePassword ""
        keyAlias "debug"
        keyPassword ""
    }
    production {
        storeFile file("release.keystore.jks")
        storePassword  ""
        keyAlias "release"
        keyPassword  ""
    }
} 
buildTypes {
    production{
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.production
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug{
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```